# Use of & bit operator against datatypes c

Tags: c

Hi I stumbled upon this line of code written in c:

```c
uint64_t rsp = (uint64_t) & (base);
```

where base is also a variable of type uint64_t.

Whats the effect of the AND operator between a variable and a data type?

Comment: `(uint64_t)` is a type-cast operator here rather than an operand; and `&` is the unary address-of operator. `(uint64_t) & (base)` is parsed as `(uint64_t)(&base)`. It takes the address of `base` and casts it to `uint64_t`.

Comment: `&` isn't a bit operator in this context. It's the "address of" operator. That line of code is misleadingly formatted.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that the & was intented to be used as the address operator.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the way this line has been formatted adds to the confusion.  In C code it's common to write no space between a unary operator (`&`) and its operand (`base`). Also the `( )` around `base` are not redundant.

This is more clearer:

```
uint64_t rsp = (uint64_t)&base;
```

`&base` takes the address of `base`, and `(uint64_t)` is a cast.